# JQuery Mobile UI button breaks visually on Click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a Android app built with JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 and PhoneGap 3.3
In about 1 in 3 loads, when I click a button it pops out of place and looks terrible. Is there some type of onDeviceReady function I should be using to avoid this issue? Thanks!Here is a screenshot:

[image]

My scripts in header in case this is helpful:

```
<link href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/HomeScreenIcon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/SplashSceen.jpg"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquerymobile10.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/categories.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n6:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/overwrite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: What is this `js/jquerymobile10.3.js`?

Comment: It is part of the JQuery Mobile frame work I guess. I commented it out and it removed all of the css from the app, so it is definitely needed.

Comment: @omar any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: I don't know. Make sure you duplicate jquery and jquery mobile libraries. Try loading only jquery 1.9 and jquery mobile 1.4 and it's associate style sheet.